# embed linux console in website/using web language to communicate with fedora/linux server

Tags: php, linux, c#

I have some problem here as I want to build a website which able to communicate with fedora server to create account. 

The website will be something like this

- user will access an IP to access the website
- website is running in window web browser eg. IE, mozila
- the website will allow user to key in their own ID, username and password to create their user account

So, what I think will be is there any web language to communicate with linux/ run linux command  eg. mkdir, useradd???

The webpage need to written in what web language in order to support the requirement??Any link for reference is appreciated

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website is running on the same box as Fedora, you could use PHP's [exec()](https://www.php.net/function.exec) command to run a shell script that creates a new user, as described in [this forum post.](http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/programming-scripting/176031-solved-crafting-php-script-create-unix-user.html#post832691)

Comment: erm, sorry to ask that, what do you mean by same box as Fedora??
ya..actually i saw some reference regarding php. Any php software/ide to introduce?? i means freeware. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you're prepared to host a web server (e.g. Apache) and run PHP on the same machine that you want to create accounts on through a Web interface, then the solution I've described will work. There are lots of free PHP IDEs, but you could simply use a plain text editor to recreate the files in the forum post I mention above.

Comment: +1 - Cool idea, but this whole process sets off security red flags in my mind. The php page for exec() mentions this to alleviate some concern: "When allowing user-supplied data to be passed to this function, use escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() to ensure that users cannot trick the system into executing arbitrary commands. "

Comment: @JMC I agree that allowing the creation of linux users via an unsecured web interface could open big security holes and is generally a Very Bad Idea, but perhaps @NewBirth has good reason to adopt this approach. Very good point about using [escapeshellarg().](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php)

Answer (score 0):

I think python is a best choice for both administration purpose and web development, 
Fedora itself using it for installation and administration purpose, and its very powerful in this field,
and its easy to learn and extends, please follow these tow links to learn more about python:

python website: http://python.org
cherrypy web framework : http://www.cherrypy.org/
python subprocess for command line execution : http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html